# Unit Testing events in karma angular 2 application

Tags: angular, events, mocking, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to unit test the method abc(Event) using karma. I have a dropdown in my view page which has 4 options  which up on change will trigger abc(Event) method.

Here is my view page:

```
<div class="myClass">
<select (change)="abc($event)" id="my">
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
    <option value="three">Three</option>
    <option value="four">Four</option>
</select>
```

my component.ts file contains the definition of method abc.

```
import {Component,OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { LocaleService } from '../../../services/locale.service';
@Component({
selector: 'app-localeselector',
templateUrl: './localeselector.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./localeselector.component.scss']
})


export class LocaleselectorComponent implements OnInit{

 private localeService: any;
 private language;
 constructor() { }

 ngOnInit() { }

}

abc(ev: Event) {
    //something...
}
}
```

How can I test method abc? Also how to mock $event?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could just create an instance of `LocaleselectorComponent` component and call `abc`. Also, you constructor can be removed.

Comment: @AluanHaddad: How can I mock the event while calling method abc?

Comment: @AmitChigadani: Tried mocking the Event object. But no positive result :(

Comment: All you need to do is pass in an object

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, it worked!!! :) I found the solution. Was able to mock the event by sending in an object.

```js
it('should work', () => {
    component.abc({ srcElement: { value: 'xyz' } });
    expect(someMethod.getValue()).toEqual('xyz');
});
```

I also changed the abc method in my component.ts file to

```js
abc($event){
    //do something...
}
```